# pass JSON data in ajax and use it in database query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I want to pass 'user_data' stored in local storage in $.getJSON and perform a  php mysql query. Code I am using is:

```
<script>
 data = localStorage.getItem("user_data");

   $(document).ready(function(){

  $.getJSON("query.php"  , {user: data},

    function(data){ /*do something*/

  });

  });
  </script>
```

Query.php

```
<? php
if( $_REQUEST["user"] )
{
    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];

    $user_data = json_encode($user).id;

    $userid = $user_data.id;

    $username = $user_data.name;

    /*Database connection*/
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");


$sql = /*database query*/;


?>
```

Basically I am passing the user_data as string in $.getJSON and then using json_encode to change it to JSON data and use it to get different attributes of user. However  I am not getting $userid and $username correctly inside query.php? Can anyone tell me how to send JSON type data and use it in php.

Comment: `json_encode` generates a string.

Comment: 1) You should be using `json_decode` instead. 2) I think you only want to access `.id` the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Add `var_dump($user_data);` to query.php to see what is available,

You should be referencing PHP arrays as `$user_data['id']`

You also need to `json_decode($user)` not encode, If using json_decode you need to reference variables as `$user_data->id` read more on how to change the output of [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode)

Also `<? php` is incorrect should be `<?php`

Your `if` statement is still open as well.

---

As @Adriano mentioned

```
<script>

 data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("user_data") );

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $.getJSON("query.php"  , {user: data},

    function(data){ /*do something*/

  });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you read from localStorage you have to deserialize the data before gets it passed to PHP:

```
<script>

 data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("user_data") );

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $.getJSON("query.php"  , {user: data},

    function(data){ /*do something*/

  });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not what he asked. PHP can de-serialize. I see your point though

Comment: What worked for me was a combination of both Zanderwar and Adriano's answers : I used JSON.parse() and user_data['id'] and dropped the json_encode inside php and it worked.

Comment: If you have the time, please post your final code, frontend/backend snippets are useful to everyone nowadays.

Comment: @Bonotoc that would be shunned and recommended for codereview. Stack isn't the place for working code

Comment: because localStorage stores data as string, if you don't deserialize it before you might get some PHP json_decode errors thrown if a user intentionally changes that value to something invalid.